# Number of five digit numbers such that the digits are non-increasing from left to right

Tags: combinatorics

10000 and 32211 would be examples of such a number.
78787 would not be.
I brute forced it by writing a Python solution and got 2001, but how do I do it mathematically?

Comment: There is a stars and bars argument, though you may have excluded $00000$ from your count

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of ways $5$ balls can be placed in $10$ bins marked $9-0$ from left to right, using stars and bars

Note that each of the $\binom{5+10−1}{10−1}$ results minus one (for all zeroes)= $2001$ thus obtained can yield only one non-increasing sequence.

A result of $\;\;\fbox{1}\fbox{0}\fbox{0}\fbox{2}\fbox{0}\fbox{0}\fbox{0}\fbox{0}\fbox{1}\fbox{1}\;$ e.g.

means obtaining $96610$